# How to populate a listview in a button Click. C# Metro app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have a list view. I populate it from a list collection from back end. I want it to get populated when a button is clicked.

My List its global:

```
List<Collection> ResourceList;

ResourceList = new List<Collection>();
```

My button

```
 <AppBarButton x:Name="btnDocuments" Height="92" Width="82" Label="Documents" Click="btnDocuments_Click"> 
      <AppBarButton.Icon> 
           <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/doc.png"  Margin="8,5,7,7"/> 
      </AppBarButton.Icon> 
 </AppBarButton>
```

My Button Click.

```
 private void btnDocuments_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {              
             ResourceList.Add(new Collection { ID = 1, Name = "hi" });       
         }
```

It gets populated when I call this method at the launch of the view but not inside a click event.

Can someone kindly help me do this. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you subscribe to this event?

Comment: sorry I didnt get you

Comment: Can you show how you create this button?

Comment: <AppBarButton x:Name="btnDocuments" Height="92" Width="82" Label="Documents" Click="btnDocuments_Click">
                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/doc.png" Margin="8,5,7,7"/>
                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                            </AppBarButton>

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger? Does it go in this method when you click a button?

Comment: yes and this line gets skipped..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99177/discussion-between-valentin-and-kirushan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might change your List<> for an ObservableCollection<>

```
List<Collection> ResourceList;
ResourceList = new List<Collection>();
```

Becomes

```
ObservableCollection<Collection> ResourceList;
ResourceList = new ObservableCollection<Collection>();
```